# What is best suitable partition style in this situation MBR or GPT

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, windows-8.1, ubuntu-14.04

I have a drive **80GB ( Formatted as Primary 1 Partition - MBR )** installed Windows 8.1 64bit.

Second, **500GB** using for Ubuntu 14.04LTS 64bit ( Dual Boot )

Third, I bought recently **1000GB** want to use as 1 partition for data drive for both Operating Systems.

Please suggest what is the proper partition style **( MBR or GPT )** and how should I format this drive in my case?

Comment: MBR simple recovery after crush HDD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you should do for your 1TB Drive with a Single Partition to work on Ubuntu and Windows:

1. Ubuntu allows writing files to `NTFS` out of the box.
2. Windows supports `NTFS` to it's full capacity of course, as it's their own Microsoft technology.
3. Since the partition on the drive is going to be `NTFS`, and it's going to be the only partition, you should use `MBR`. It works well with `NTFS`.

You should use GPT only when you have complex partitioning needs and huge drive capacities. For example:

- `MBR` allows a maximum of 4 primary partitions. We can overcome this with GPT.
- `MBR` allows a maximum partition size of 2TB. We can overcome this with GPT.
- Booting from a GPT volume to a Windows environment requires a system with UEFI and 64-bit support.

**Conclusion**:

Keep it simple and easy, and use `NTFS` with `MBR`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use GPT, because it is the newer partition style. Linux supports GPT.
The filesystem depends what are planing to do and what are your security concerns.
I would recommend ntfs, when you use this 1000 GB disk only a data pool. This filessystem is reachable from both OSs.